# andengine Sprite setPosition not working

Tags: arrays, andengine, sprite

I am making a game where when you click the screen the first and second time it creates a portal. For the third click I want the first portal to move to the location of my third click. This is my onSceneTouchEvent:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
        {
         Sprite[] portal = new Sprite[10];
         if (portalCounter <= 2)
            {
             if(portalCounter == 0){
                 portal[0] =  new Sprite(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY(), resourcesManager.platform1_region, vbom);
                 attachChild(portal[0]);
                 portalCounter++;
             }
             else if(portalCounter == 1){
                 portal[1] =  new Sprite(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY(), resourcesManager.platform1_region, vbom);
                 attachChild(portal[1]);
                 portalCounter++;
             }
             else if(portalCounter == 2){
                 portal[0].setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
             } 
       }
   }
    return false;
}
```

Problem is that the setPosition is not working. Program crashes on third click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time in `onSceneTouchEvent` you creat new empty array `Sprite[] portal = new Sprite[10];`.

```
else if(portalCounter == 2){
    portal[0].setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
}
```

portal[0] is null

Comment: Oh Thankyou For The Answer. How Would I Create Just One Array And Use It Each time?

Comment: You can create array as field of class `private Sprite[] portal = new Sprite[10];`